# Pandas style.bar color based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

How can I render a Pandas df where one of the columns' `style.bar.color` property is computed based on some condition?

Example:

```
df.style.bar(subset=['before', 'after'], color='#ff781c', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
```

[image]

Instead of having both columns highlight with `#ff781c`, I'd like one of the columns (`df['before']`) to remain that same constant color, and the other column (`df['after']`) to be computed as:

```
def compute_color(row):
   if row['after'] >= row['before']:
      return 'red'
   else:
      return 'green
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included code to generate your dataframe.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'before': [2, 4, 6], 'after': [1, 5, 6]}, index=['liters', 'drive', 'Make'])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do is to use `pd.IndexSlice` to create subset for `df.style.bar`:

```
i_pos = pd.IndexSlice[df.loc[(df['after']>df['before'])].index, 'after']
i_neg = pd.IndexSlice[df.loc[~(df['after']>df['before'])].index, 'after']
df.style.bar(subset=['before'], color='#ff781c', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)\
  .bar(subset=i_pos, color='green', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)\
  .bar(subset=i_neg, color='red', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly color each cell in column.

```
    rows = 10
    indx = list(df.index)[-rows:]  # indices of the last 10 rows
    # Colormap for the last 10 rows in a Column
    last10 = df['Column'][-rows:]  # values to color
    colors = [color_map_color(e, cmap_name='autumn_r', vmin=100, vmax=1000) for e in last10]  # colors
    values = [pd.IndexSlice[indx[i], 'Column'] for i in range(rows)]  # for .bar subset

    html = (df.style
            .bar(subset=values[0], color=colors[0], vmax=1000, vmin=0, align='left', width=100)
            .bar(subset=values[1], color=colors[1], vmax=1000, vmin=0, align='left', width=100)
            .bar(subset=values[2], color=colors[2], vmax=1000, vmin=0, align='left', width=100)

            )
    html
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeUV0.jpg